# Why Are My Objects Invisble?

Tags: objects, 3d-view

Whenever I create a new later or object, the object is invisible.
There is an orange outline when selected, and a black outline when not selected. 
I can see the object fine when I go into vitiate paint, weight paint, or texture paint. Why is this?
Also, when I select the plane, the camera gets selected, too. Not sure if it's juts my freshness to the program, or if it is a problem.

Comment: Would probably be easier to troubleshot if you post the blend file.

Comment: Sounds like your 3dview may be in [wireframe shading](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/shading.html#shading-modes).